# is there any way to continue Bluetooth Low Energy scan,never stop for a android app

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I 'm developping a continue scan android app,   because I have to collect some important info from another  device  , I have to scan ble device,and never stop, otherwise, I may miss some important info. Is there any way for a android app to continue Bluetooth Low Energy  scan,never stop  ,scan for a year if the important device don't  appear.  During the year, my android phone always  keep sufficient electricity，but sometimes I will press home button  ， sometimes I will make Screen Off (not power off ,just make screen off).

Comment: Is this for a off-the-shelf consumer device (phone) OR business owned hardware OR custom Android device?

Comment: a phone ,for example huawei, Samsung , xiaomi  and so on

Comment: You could also establish a connection to the device. Then you will instantly get the data when it sends a notification. With autoConnect = true when calling connectGatt, Android will also automatically reconnect "indefinitely".

Answer (score 1):

Modern Android has implemented various battery saving measures which will prevent you from continuous data collection.

1. [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) is implemented by the Android framework. See: [Scanning for Bluetooth LE devices when the phone is in doze mode, don't work. CallBack method doesn't called when doze mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62961270/295004)
2. Additionally various device manufacturers have implemented their own battery savings systems which will kill your app even when you are following Android framework rules. See: https://dontkillmyapp.com/ for details.